# SSIS execution error :Executed as user: cam\Package.Runner. The step did not generate any output.

Tags: sql, ssis

I'm executing one `SSIS job` daily which i have schedule in `sql server agent`.

The package executes succesfully daily but I'm getting step failure message below :

please elaborate more why is it so

```
Date        4/19/2013 9:43:01 AM
Log     Job History (Reporting)

Step ID     13
Server      PROD
Job Name        Reporting
Step Name       R1: Load_Data
Duration        00:00:05
Sql Severity        0
Sql Message ID      0
Operator Emailed        
Operator Net sent       
Operator Paged      
Retries Attempted       0

Message
Executed as user: cam\Package.Runner. The step did not generate any output.  Process Exit Code 1.  The step failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on exception message, I can see your data has been changed and this step query or return nothing. You should check your data.

Comment: Yes I'm returning nothing only importing prices into database table from .csv file